# select a field values that are not found in another table

Tags: mysql

I need a query which should results a fields that are not found in another table.  Let say,

**table 1:**

```
comp    col1    col2    col3   col4
----------------------------------
nam1      1       1       b      c
nam2      0       0       abc    c
nam3      1       1       a      c
nam4      1       1       b      c
nam5      0       0       c      c
```

**table2:**

```
name     col1    col2
----------------------
b          3       f
a          4       f
c          5       f
```

**result:**

```
comp  col3   col4
----------------------
nam2   abc     c
```

the result be based on `col3,col1=0,col2=0` on first table and name in second table..abc is not found in table2...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but if I understood you correctly, you want to select all rows from `table1` where `col1` and `col2` are both 0, and `col3` is not contained in the name column of `table2`. If so, your query should be simple enough:

```
SELECT comp, col3, col4
  FROM table1
 WHERE col1 = 0
   AND col2 = 0
   AND col3 NOT IN (SELECT name FROM table2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the explanation the joining key between table1 and table2 is

```
table1.col3 = table2.name
```

Using this you can use the following query

```
select 
t1.comp,
t1.col3,
t1.col4
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.name = t1.col3
where t2.name is null
```